# Save data from LIST to text file

Tags: c#, list, text-files

I'm using this library http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library to record a macro.
I want to know how to save the "events" in a text file to load them later?

So, here is the LIST:

```
List<MacroEvent> events = new List<MacroEvent>();
```

What I need to do to get the data into a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use the ToString() method in order to export the MacroEvent to a formatted text. You probably need to override the default implementation. Make sure to put all the information you need, otherwise you won't be able to retrieve them later. Reading and parsing the file is then needed to load the data.
2. Use the builtin .net XML serialization feature. Write/Read operation is straightforward.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813
3. If you are not planning on using the data on another application, why not use the BinarySerializer? By far, the best method, but the resulting file won't be in text format.

   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

Comment: The BinarySerializer is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `MacroEvent` has a `ToString()` method available to it, you can simply iterate through the list and print to your text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("myFile.txt");
foreach (MacroEvent item in events)
{
    tw.WriteLine(item.ToString());   
}
tw.Close();
```

Comment: I've already tried with something like this, but it doesn't work.
I'm getting just "GlobalMacroRecorder.MacroEvent" in the text file.
Thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using an extension method. I don't know anything about the `MacroEvent` and am not planning on downloading the code off of Code Project just to take a look, but here is what it might look like.

```
public static class MacroEventExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToFile(this List<MacroEvent> events, string path)
    {
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var e in events)
        {
            fileContents.AppendLine("{0}::{1}",
                [some event id from the object],
                [some event message from the object]);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(path, fileContents.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then in the above code you just call:

```
events.WriteToFile([some path])
```